# npm commands are not working

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have installed Node.js and at first when I wrote an npm command like `npm install -g <>` or `npm start` it worked, but now it doesn't. I removed and installed node again and am still facing the same problem:

```
~$ npm install
~$
```

No action is made and the terminal returns back to normal.

Comment: `npm install --verbose`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have node installed? Run "node -v"

Comment: no reply,I know that it should give me the node version it worked with me when I first installed nodejs but I have removed it and re installed.The command that is used is sudo apt-get install -y nodejs isn't that right ??

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` looks for a `package.json` file in your current directory. It installs all the dependencies listed in the `package.json`. Similarly `npm start` looks in the `package.json` scripts to see what command it should really run. If it doesn't work now, you are probably in the wrong directory. If you are in the correct directory, can you provide more information like the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: I have written these in dependencies  package.json{
    "name": "test"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true,
  "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www"
    },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "mongodb": "~2.0.33",
    "monk": "~1.0.1"
}
} then I went to the terminal and this was what happened
~/Documents/test$ npm install  and ~/Documents/test$ 
 is what the terminal shows and nothing else